# How to combine two tables in SQL (MySQL)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I want to combine between two table. The output should be data from table A, table B.

```
 SELECT date as Date, COUNT(*) as Transaction, SUM(status=0) as Success 
 FROM transfer_tx_201503 WHERE time >='00:00:00' AND time <= '$searchterm' 
 UNION SELECT date as Date, COUNT(*) as Transaction, SUM(status=0) as Success FROM request_tx_201503 WHERE time >='00:00:00' AND time <= '$searchterm' GROUP BY date desc"
```

i want out put like this: |2015-03-23 |  5  |  3  |  4   |   1   |

5 and 3 from table transfer_tx_2015, 4 and 1 from table request_tx_2015

Thank you

Comment: you can use concept of join    http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: can you edit with more info about your tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common field is the date field, hence the join should be on that field.
Try using the following SQL:

```
SELECT t.date as Date, COUNT(*) as Transaction, SUM(t.status=0) as Success, COUNT(*) as Request, SUM(r.status=0) as RequestSuccess 
FROM transfer_tx_201503 AS t,request_tx_201503 AS r WHERE t.time >='00:00:00' AND t.time <= '$searchterm' AND t.date=r.date
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use table_a, table_b syntax:

```
SELECT columns FROM table_a, table_b WHERE table_a.id = table_b.id
```

Or you can use JOIN:

```
SELECT columns FROM table_a JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id
```

You can read more about JOIN in:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT columns 
FROM firstTable 
JOIN secondTable ON 
    firstTable.columnName = secondTable.columnName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT coloumn FROM Table_One, Table_Two WHERE Table_One.coloumnName = Table_One.coloumnName
```